# add data target attribute to the button element after clicking

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

I am new to the `react js`. Here, I do have a modal which is like ->

**ErrorComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';


export default class ErrorComponent extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            ...
      </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}





**LowLeveLCriteria.js**

   class LowLevelCriteria extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            technologies: this.props.techData,
            lowData: this.props.lowData.low,
            showModal: false
        }
    }

 validate (v1, v2) {  return "1" }


    onaddRow(e, id) {
            const errors = this.validate("value1", "value2");

            if (errors === "1") {
            } else {
                this.setState({
            showModal: true
        })
               }


        render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="questionLevelIndication">
                    <span className="levelIndicatorBtn backgroundColorForLow">
                        1
                    </span>
                    <label className="levelIndicationLabel">
                        Low Difficulty Level - Maximum 6 questions
                    </label>
                </div>
                {(this.props.lowData) && this.props.lowData.Low.length > 0 && this.props.lowData.Low.map(data => (
                    <LowRow technologies={this.state.technologies} onChange={this.onchange.bind(this)} data={data} key={data.id} onAddRow={this.onaddRow.bind(this)} onRemoveRow={this.onRemoveRow.bind(this)} />
                ))}
                {this.state.showModal && <ErrorComponent />}
            </div>

        )
    }

<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm standard-btn-50 margin-left-10" onClick={(e) => { props.onAddRow(e, props.data.id) }}>+</button>
```

Now, Here When I click on the button which is a child element and then calls a method which is `AddRow` in the parent component. Now, Here ,what I want to do is that ,

if after clicking on that button I call one more function inside add function which validates and then returns something  . If there is an value which is  "1" then I want to show that modal to the user . So,

I am not getting a way. How  can  I do this ?  Because for opening a modal we need to have a data-target which needs to be on button, but my button is in some another component. So,

I tried with document.getElementById and then adding the data target attribute after clicking on the button . But no luck . Can any one give me a bit hint ?

Comment: Sorry, but your question seems unclear. are you trying to display a dialog using react and you fail? or is there a specific problem (adding data target?)?

Comment: I mean I have not added the data-target attribute on the button initially. But when user clicks that button and if some conditions fails then I want to show user a dialog . But for the dialog I need to have the data target attribute on the button itself. How do I add that attribute after failing some conditions and then show that model.

Comment: I think you are looking for boostrap modal box, here is the simple modal box link using react boostrap. https://codepen.io/nsieber/pen/grGpzW

Comment: one more way which is similar to your code is this: https://jsfiddle.net/sqfhkdcy/ . hope these 2 solutions will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

All sub-components you try to render should be within component's `render()` method.

If I'm not mistaken, you're trying to render `<ErrorComponent />` from your handler, so it will not work. If you're trying to create a stateful component using function declaration, please see first part of ref link 1.

One approach I suggest you is:

- Maintain a state `dataTarget` inside parent component and change it to `true` inside the button handler.
- Conditionally render `<ErrorComponent />` inside `render()`

When `dataTarget` state is changed inside handler, it will cause the component to re-render and `ErrorComponent` will show.

Please refer here:

1. https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html
2. https://www.robinwieruch.de/conditional-rendering-react/

Comment: Sorry but I am not still getting this

Comment: Can you give me a JS fiddle?